# How to measure time between clicks in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, button, stopwatch

Hello so I want to make a code that does this. I keep clicking and if the time between clicks is >= 2000ms then write something in label else keep clicking.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    double tt = 2000;
    double duration = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sw.Start();
        if (duration >= tt)
        {
            label1.Text = "Speed reached!";
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Stop();
            duration = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please state your question - it is unclear what help you need.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson How can I measure time between clicks then when time is lets say bigger or equals to 2000ms something happends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want something like this:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
double tt = 2000;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw.Stop();
    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= tt)
    {
        label1.Text = "Speed reached!";
    }
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
}
```

This will start a stopwatch on the first click and then on each click it will measure the time between the clicks.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as follows:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Stop();

        if (sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds >= tt)
        {
            label1.Text = "Speed reached!";
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sw.ElapsedMilliseconds is a value type, not a reference type
If you assign it to a variable and ElapsedMilliseconds changes
your variable won't change

Also, put start at the end of your code
This should work

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    double tt = 2000;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= tt)
        {
            label1.Text = "Speed reached!";
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Stop();
            sw.Reset();
        }
        sw.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["PrevClickTime"] = Session["PrevClickTime"] ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    if (((DateTime)Session["PrevClickTime"]).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Milliseconds >= 2000)
    {
        label1.Text = "Speed reached!";
    }
    else
    {
        // do y
    }
    Session["PrevClickTime"] = DateTime.Now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach where you could **remove the click event handler on each click** and **start a timer for 2 seconds** and on the tick of the timer, **attach the click event handler again**.
Here is the sample code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 2000  }; // here time in milliseconds
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // event handler of your button
{
    button1.Click -= button1_Click; // remove the event handler for now

    label1.Text = "Speed reached!";

    // remove already attached tick handler if any, otherwise the handler would be called multiple times
    timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Click += button1_Click; // attach the event handler again
    timer.Stop();
}
```